# Kotlin generics on sealed class won't compile with type check fails

Tags: kotlin, generics

Imagine we have a data structure like this

```
sealed class ResultOf {
    class Success<out T>(
        val value: T
    ) : ResultOf()

    class Failure(
        val exception: Exception
    ) : ResultOf()
}
```

This works fine:

```
inline fun <reified T> ResultOf.doIfFailure(callback: (exception: Exception) -> Unit) {
    if (this is ResultOf.Failure) {
        callback(exception)
    }
}
```

But the following won't compile with compile problems over `ResultOf.Success` & `callback(value)`

```
inline fun <reified T> ResultOf.doIfSuccess(callback: (value: T) -> Unit) {
    if (this is ResultOf.Success) {
        callback(value)
    }
}
```

> One type argument expected. Use 'Success<*>' if you don't want to pass type arguments

I'm guessing this is something to do with type erasure? But can't quite find anything which explains why. Also, is there a way round this? (Without putting a generic on `ResultOf`)?

Comment: Did you meant to do: `if (this is ResultOf.Success<T>)`?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't compile either :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reified types only work in inline functions. Class types are never reified. At run-time, there is no way to tell what the type of `Success<T>` is.

You could manually track the type by adding a class parameter to the class constructor, and casting in your function like this.

```
sealed class ResultOf {
    class Success<out T: Any>(
            val cls: KClass<out T>,
            val value: T
    ) : ResultOf()

    class Failure(
            val exception: Exception
    ) : ResultOf()
}

inline fun <reified T> ResultOf.doIfSuccess(callback: (value: T) -> Unit) {
    if (this is ResultOf.Success<*> && cls == T::class) {
        callback(value as T)
    }
}
```

It's not a great design, though, because you could use `doOnSuccess` with the wrong value type and it would silently do nothing even on success. I would just put the type in the `ResultOf` class definition. Then you don't need to use a reified function or even do any casting:

```
sealed class ResultOf<out T> {
    class Success<out T>(
            val value: T
    ) : ResultOf<T>()

    class Failure(
            val exception: Exception
    ) : ResultOf<Nothing>()
}

inline fun <T: Any> ResultOf<T>.doIfSuccess(callback: (value: T) -> Unit) {
    if (this is ResultOf.Success<T>) {
        callback(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that `T` is `out`-projected, you can even remove the type parameter from `Failure` and make it specialize the supertype as `ResultOf<Nothing>`.